# HTML is showing in election page - give me a `<br>`

Tags: bug, election

This happened while voting on Academia Stack Exchange today. Not the biggest of priorities, of course, but still, figured I should throw it up here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report! :D

Comment: Man I swear I searched for it, I promise!!

Comment: No worries.  The title of the other one is kinda odd.